# android искаженное отображение searchView

Tags: android

Есть активити со стандартным SearchView. В какой-то момент SearchView наклонился как на картинке. Как сделать его нормальным? Пробовал на 5.0, 7.1 андроидах

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @pavlofff нет сакрального смысла. Изменил. Написал по привычке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решается установкой background атрибута у searchview

Comment: Мб особенность оболочки на устройстве?

Comment: Возможно. Но это появлялось и на MIUI 9 и на обычном Андроиде 5.0